# Not able to run the application just by copying node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, npm-install, node-modules

I am running a PreactJS (same as ReactJS) app. We use webapck to build the app. until very recently developers were able to copy node_modules folder from source repository and they were able to run the application.

Recently we updated all node modules and now every developer has to run `npm install` command in order to run the app. Simply copying node_modules folder does not work anymore.

I understand this is the right way to work but lot of time due to restriction on my companies side, developers struggle with getting node modules from internet. That is why we adopted this approach.

This is how package.json look:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "ion-rangeslider": "^2.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "preact": "^8.3.1",
    "preact-router": "^2.6.1",
    "preact-async-route": "^2.2.1",
    "promise-polyfill": "^8.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.1.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "compression": "^1.7.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.6.0",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "less": "^3.8.1",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.2",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "ncp": "^2.0.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "regexp-replace-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack": "^4.19.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.8"
  }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
C:\MyApp\trunk\node_modules\@xtuc\long\src\long.js:24
export default function Long(low, high, unsigned) {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\MyApp\trunk\node_modules\@xtuc\long\index.js:1:80)
```

**Questions:**

1. What is the right way to resolve this issue?
2. Why do I have to run npm install command to get my app working? Is should work just by copying node modules? If my assumption is wrong, what do I need to learn in this situation.

**in webpack.config, I do have rule which tells babel to exclude node_modules.**

```
  rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That one package you are consuming is in a format that node.js does not understand. It is expecting `commonjs` format  but it is getting the newer ES6 modules( see for more info for example https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/ ). Normally packages on NPM (which are installed to your `node_modules` are in `commonjs` format so you wouldn't need to transpile third-party code, but only your own code.

Weirdly enough, [that package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@xtuc/long) has a commonjs version. It looks like something like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) (or another transpiler is trying to read every file in your `node_modules`. (which shouldn't happen!) If you share your `package.json`, we could see if any script is triggered.

Comment: I have updated the question to include list of node modules I am using in my application. What you just said makes sense. But how did you came this conclusion `That one package you are consuming is in a format that node.js does not understand`

Comment: As soon as you encounter "import" or "export" you know it's not commonjs.  Transpilers like babel take care of transpiling the "import/exports" to "require / module.exports ". See http://2ality.com/2015/12/babel-commonjs.html  for more info about the formats. Could you also add the webpack.config.js? I am pretty sure it's babel not excluding the node_modules folder. From your package.json I can't see what is being called because it's not complete. It's missing the opening brace and stuff like package name and most importantly scripts.

Comment: nodejs choking on this part in your example: `export default function Long(low, high, unsigned) {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export`

Comment: I do see this snippet in webpack.config `  rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },` which is telling babel to exclude node modules? Is it not working or its just excluding `.jsx` files only

Answer (score 1):

1. The right solution is to set up a local mirror of NPM's registry, probably with a package like [verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio) or [local-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-npm). You'd have to set this up once on your local network and ensure it has internet access.
2. `npm install` might do different things depending on the machine it's running on. For example, a module might compile a library on MacOS, but use a bundled binary on Windows. Copying `node_modules` would only consistently work with every package if the machine that generated `node_modules` was identical to your development machine. You shouldn't even have `node_modules` checked into your source control system, just the `package.json` and maybe the lockfile.